# Applying Angular directive ngCloak to a single Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was playing with this [toy Angular JS application](http://plnkr.co/edit/MVaYJD) and tried to use the [ngCloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) directive to hide the templating markup at startup. When applied to the tag where I declare the app module, everything works fine:

```
<div ng-app="EditorErrante" ng-cloak>
```

but when I try to cloak only the second Controller:

```
<div id="stats" ng-controller="Statistiche" ng-cloak>
```

<del>nothing happens</del> the directive has no effect: I can still see the markup in the "stats" div before it gets processed.
I tried adding the directive as a class and copying the CSS rule in the stylesheet. Still nothing.

Anybody know why this happens?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens?

Comment: That I can still see the markup in the "stats" div when the page is loading, just as if there was no directive. OK, bad wording. Maybe I should rephrase it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a style in your stylesheet:

```
.ng-cloak { display:none; }
```

Then use ng-cloak as a class instead of an attribute:

```
<div id="stats" ng-controller="Statistiche" class="ng-cloak">
```

e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/xWPW2i?p=preview

should work now.

Remember, you can use directives as classes as well, not just attributes and elements.

Edit, just tested this, and you dont have to put it into a class. So just add the .ng-cloak style into your stylesheet.

Comment: Hello! Hiding the div is not a problem, since it will eventually reside in its own file. I wanted to understand why the Angular directive works the way it does, that is only when applied to the whole app since, being a CSS trick, that shouldn't really matter.